# How to get runOnUiThread to run continuously in Android

Tags: android, loops, while-loop

Using Android studio, I am trying to make an app that gets data from a web-service and display the data and updates the view every 5 sec or when the data on the web-service changes. With this I am trying to change the colours on some button based on an `int`, the **int** changes and the color on the button changes when I apply `buttons();` to another button and then presses it but I want it to update by itself.

When I used a while loop the app gets stuck

```
MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

          buttons();

        }
    });
```

The `runOnUiThread` is placed in the `onCreate`.

Comment: This is not a good idea,use AlarmManager and config it for 5sec and inside broadcast receiver you can call web service and do what ever you want to do inside onSucces call back of your web service

Answer (score 1):

using run on UI thread will cause your UI to freeze , try using a timer task instead . 
example :

```
 @Override
    public void StopTimerTask() {
        if (timer != null) {
            timer.cancel();
            timer = null;
        }
    }

    public void StartTimer() {
        timer = new Timer();
        initializeTimerTask();
        int UpdateTime = Integer.valueOf(UserSettings.getString("Update", "60000"));
        timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, YOURTIME);
    }
   public void initializeTimerTask() {

        doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                myHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        YOUR LOGIC HERE 
                    }
                });
            }
        };

    }
```

Comment: and do you call those 3 methods from the OnCreate ?

Comment: i call the StartTimerTask() on OnCreate , just make sure to call StopTimerTask() when your task need to stop such as onpause to avoid related problems

Answer (score 0):

doing this where u just put another class into main activity was succesful only problem is that it have to be in my main class

```
 public class updategui extends TimerTask {
                Activity context;
                Timer timer;

                public updategui(Activity context, int seconds) {
                    this.context = context;
                    timer = new Timer();
                    timer.schedule(this,
                            seconds * 1000,  // initial delay
                            seconds * 1000); // subsequent rate
                }

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(context == null || context.isFinishing()) {
                        this.cancel();
                        return;
        }

        context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {
                    buttons();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }}
```